# Windows Security Incompatible Driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, security

Running Windows 10 Pro 21H1  Build 19043.1081. I was trying to turn on Device Security to be told I had an Incompatible Driver.

The file is `PxHlpa64.sys` (Corel Corporation) Driver Version 3.1.1.0 and it is found on my machine at the following locations:

- `C:\Windows\System32\drivers`

and

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\sonic Shared\PX Drivers`

Is there any way to find out which Installation Program generated these files?

I have Process Explorer but I do not think that it looks for this type of file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a DVD Driver.  If it is not working, check that the DVD is working and search the DVD maker for another driver.

Microsoft maintains a database of drivers. You might try using the Windows driver.

[DVD Driver](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/PxHlpa64.sys-26946.html)

> PXHLPA64.SYS Information
>
> This is a valid program that is required to run at startup.
>
> This program is required to run on startup in order to benefit from
> its functionality or so that the program will work.
>
> The following information is a brief description of what is known
> about this file. If you require further assistance for this file, feel
> free to ask about in the forums
>
> Name PxHlpa64 FilenamePxHlpa64.sys  CommandC
> :\Windows\System32\Drivers\PxHlpa64.sys
>
> Description  Sonic DVD/CD Driver.
>
> File Location %System%\Drivers\PxHlpa64.sys
>
> Startup Type  This startup entry is a Windows Driver. A driver is a
> program, that when started, allows Windows to communicate with
> specific hardware or virtual devices that are installed on your
> computer. Therefore, if you disable a Windows Driver, the piece of
> hardware that it was designed to work with may no longer work or have
> limited functionality.

Comment: Hi there, My DVD is an ASUS drive and it works fine. It was Windows 10 that said that this driver was incompatible when I tried to turn on Device Security, it did not say why. I was not disabling the driver.  Comments Please. Regards, David

Comment: Try completely removing the DVD device and any drivers.  Restart the computer and then install the DVD again.

Comment: Microsoft maintains a database of drivers.  When you have restarted, try using the Windows driver.